# returning null using ifelse function

Tags: r

I am trying to return null using ifelse in R. But it throws an error message. Any suggestion please.

Here is my code:

```
cntr1 <- ifelse(unlist(gregexpr("---",path_info[j], fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)) > 0, 3 * length(unlist(gregexpr("---",path_info[j], fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE))),NULL )
```

Error message is:

```
Error in ifelse(unlist(gregexpr("---", path_info[j], fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)) >  : 
  replacement has length zero In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. From the help page of `ifelse`, section `Value`: `A vector of the same length [...] as test and data values from the values of yes or no`. And `length(NULL)` returns zero so your `no` can't even be recycled.

Comment: I don't know if it will really be useful to you but maybe try instead of returning `NULL` to return `"NULL"` so that your ifelse works and then do a `eval(parse(text = ...) )` to really get the `NULL` to appear ?

Comment: Why would you need it to return `NULL` anyway? You cannot have `NULL`s in atomic vectors anyway. `NA` is the right object for missing values in R.

Comment: @LyzandeR use of NA does not give length 0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I came up with three different approaches to return `NULL` in an ifelse-like scenario.

In this scenario b should be `NULL` when a is `NULL`

```
a <- NULL
is.null(a)  #TRUE

b <- switch(is.null(a)+1,"notNullHihi",NULL)
b <- if(is.null(a)) NULL else {"notNullHihi"}
b <- unlist(ifelse(is.null(a),list(NULL),"notNullHihi"))

is.null(b)  #TRUE for each of them
```

Comment: The `unlist` approach can be more annoying as it can modify an object in the `FALSE` case (e.g. if you want to return a `data.frame`)

Comment: That's a good illustration why programming in R is painful. These small annoying things that one stumbles over again and again. And most of the time, the error message won't really tell you why you F failed, and you have to go inside it, execute code line by line and see what eventually falls.

Answer (score 4):

I needed a similar functionality in one of my recent applications. This is how I came up with a solution.

```
obj <- "val1"

# Override a with null (this fails)
newobj <- ifelse(a == "val1", NULL, a)

# Separating the ifelse statement to if and else works

if(obj == "val1") newobj <- NULL else newobj <- obj
```

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, where `yes` and `no` of `ifelse` are single-element vectors, you can try to return the results as lists

```
ifelse(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),list(1),list(NULL))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#NULL
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1
```

This approach would also work if either of `yes` or `no` are multi-element lists. See for instance

```
x=as.list(1:3)
y=c(as.list(letters[1:2]),list(NULL))
ifelse(x<2,x,y)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "b"
#
#[[3]]
#NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

use `switch()` rather than `ifelse()` if you want to return `NULL`

reference:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/02/use-switch-instead-of-ifelse-to-return-a-null/