# ggplot2 facet grid with conditional facets and tidy evaluation

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, tidyeval

I want to create a function that produces a `ggplot` plot and provide an *optional* argument for a facetting variable to `facet_grid()`.

In particular, if possible, I want to incorporate the conditional logic *inside* `facet_grid`. I also want to use the tidy evaluation framework - so no formula strings!

However, all of my attempts have failed.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris <- iris %>% add_column(idx = rep(1:2, 75))
```

My first attempt fails, as `facet_grid` tries to find a variable named `NULL` (with backticks).

```
plot_iris <- function(df_in, facet_var = NULL){
  ggplot(df_in) +
    geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    facet_grid(vars(!!enquo(facet_var)), vars(idx))
}

plot_iris(iris)

#> Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `NULL`.
#> * Plot is missing `NULL`
#> * Layer 1 is missing `NULL`
```

Running `plot_iris(iris, Species)`, however, works as expected.

My second attempt also fails, but with a different error message.

```
plot_iris2 <- function(df_in, facet_var = NULL){
  facet_quo <- enquo(facet_var)

  ggplot(df_in) +
    geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    facet_grid(rows = ifelse(identical(facet_quo, quo(NULL)), NULL,
                             vars(!!facet_quo)),
               cols = vars(idx))
}

plot_iris2(iris)

#> Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
#>   replacement has length zero
#> In addition: Warning message:
#> In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
```

Running this attempt with a non-`NULL` optional argument also fails:

```
plot_iris2(iris, Species)

#> Error: `rows` must be `NULL` or a `vars()` list if `cols` is a `vars()` list
```

My third attempt also fails, with the same error message but a different warning:

```
plot_iris3 <- function(df_in, facet_var = NULL){
  facet_quo <- enquo(facet_var)

  ggplot(df_in) +
    geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(ifelse(identical(facet_quo, quo(NULL)), NULL,
                                  !!facet_quo)))
}

plot_iris3(iris)

#> Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
#>   replacement has length zero
#> In addition: Warning message:
#> In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
#>   'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Using a non-`NULL` optional argument returns a plot faceted by `idx` but not `Species` - there is a facet label for the single row, labelled by "1".

```
plot_iris3(iris, Species)
```

Are there any alternatives that use conditional logic inside a single `facet_grid` call, and that work when the optional argument is `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe we should remove `NULL` elements from vars specs to make this easier. I have opened an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2986

You can use `rlang::quo_is_null()` to check for `quo(NULL)`. I would do it in a separate step for clarity.

```
plot_iris <- function(df_in, facet_var = NULL){
  facet_quo <- enquo(facet_var)

  if (rlang::quo_is_null(facet_quo)) {
    rows <- vars()
  } else {
    rows <- vars(!!facet_quo)
  }

  ggplot(df_in) +
    geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    facet_grid(rows, vars(idx))
}
```

Comment: I tried to extend this by having two optional facet arguments, it seems like in that case, `facet_grid(vars() vars())` will fail? Thanks!

Comment: Is this issue relevant? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3070

Answer (score 1):

I think you need your second approach.  The key is that you'll need `switch()` to return `NULL`, not `ifelse()`.  See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814810/returning-null-using-ifelse-function) and discussion [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/use-switch-instead-of-ifelse-to-return-a-null/).

```
plot_iris2 <- function(df_in, facet_var = NULL){
    facet_quo <- enquo(facet_var)

    ggplot(df_in) +
        geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
        facet_grid(rows = switch(identical(facet_quo, quo(NULL)) + 1, 
                                 vars(!!facet_quo),
                                 NULL),
                   cols = vars(idx))
}

plot_iris2(iris, facet_var = NULL)
```

[image]

```
plot_iris2(iris, facet_var = Species)
```

[image]