# Conditional facet specification with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, parameter-passing, facet, facet-wrap

I am making several plots, which for flexibility I am planning to wrap in functions, and as part of that I would like to specify faceting for those plots according to some condition.

Specifically, I have a list of `grouping_vars` (per-specified elsewhere) that I use to perform several other manipulations on the data. I'd like to have my plotting functions be able to automatically use a `facet_wrap` if there's only one `grouping_var`, or if there are two or more variables specified in `grouping_var`, use the first two for `facet_grid`.

So for instance, if the basic plot is something like

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))
```

If I specify `grouping_vars <- c("cyl")`, I'd like to get, in effect,

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

Whereas if I specify `grouping_vars <- c("cyl", "carb")` I'd like to get

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    facet_grid(vars(cyl), vars(carb))
```

Based on some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340252/is-there-a-way-in-r-and-ggplot-to-create-a-facet-wrap-plot-with-a-conditional-ge) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218152/ggplot2-facet-grid-with-conditional-facets-and-tidy-evaluation) I've tried doing this:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
    {if(length(grouping_vars==1)) facet_wrap(grouping_vars[[1]])} +
    {if(length(grouping_vars>=2)) facet_grid(vars(grouping_vars[[1]]), vars(grouping_vars[[2]]))}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Among other things, if there's only one element in `grouping_vars`, it gives me `Error in grouping_vars[[2]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Is there a way to conditionally specify faceting like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the advice in the vignette [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html), we should be able to use `vars()` with the `.data` pronoun as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_mtcars <- function(grouping_vars = NULL) {
  p <- ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))
  
  if (length(grouping_vars) == 1) {

    p <- p + facet_wrap(vars(.data[[grouping_vars]]))

  } else if (length(grouping_vars) == 2) {

    p <- p + facet_grid(vars(.data[[grouping_vars[1]]]), 
                        vars(.data[[grouping_vars[2]]]))

  }
  p
}

plot_mtcars("cyl")
```

[image]

```r
plot_mtcars(c("cyl", "vs"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We can create a custom function, which uses `get` to pass the variables to `ggplot`.

```r
conditional_facet <- function(data, x, y, grp) {
  require(ggplot2)
  require(dplyr)
  data %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes({{x}}, {{y}})) -> gp
  
  if(length(grp) == 1) {
    gp + facet_wrap(~get(grp)) -> gp_out
  } else if (length(grp) == 2) {
    gp + facet_grid(vars(get(grp[1])), vars(get(grp[2]))) -> gp_out
  } else {
    gp -> gp_out
  }
  return(gp_out)
}
```

```
grouping_vars <- c("cyl")
conditional_facet(mtcars, hp, mpg, grouping_vars)
```

[image]

```
grouping_vars <- c("cyl", "carb")
conditional_facet(mtcars, hp, mpg, grouping_vars)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>